# The Page Is Refreshing Everytime When Redirecting To Another Page in Catch Error Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have no idea why the page refreshing every time when I try to redirect to another page in catch error axios

```
axios
    .get('http://localhost/my-project/laravue/api/user')
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data.name);
      user.value = response.data;
      
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response.data);
       if (error.response.status === 403) { 
          router.push('/user/login')
       } 
       return Promise.reject(error); 
    });
```

What's wrong and any solution?

Comment: What is `error.response.status` in the catch block?

Comment: It's done. It's because I call token in login page to redirect to home. So, the page is keep refreshing.